# time series Diebold-Mariano Test n-ahead forecast in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, diebold-mariano-test

I have a question about "h" in dm.test & DM.test from package forecast & multDM, assume I set a ARIMA model to forecast n-ahead = 20 (using dynamic regression not one step forecast), so taht
when I use DM.test which "h" should I define?

I have read this [article](https://www.real-statistics.com/time-series-analysis/forecasting-accuracy/diebold-mariano-test/) , seems when the n-step forecast should choose h = n^1/3 + 1 (I'm not understand about this), where n is sample = 20 ; h = 4. Then want to Know in DM.test why can't choose h = 20 ? (the output is "NA")

I copy the data from this article

```
Actual <- c(1.22884,2.6684,3.41773,2.2392,2.12256,0.4638,-0.55081,1.18295,-2.4133,0.97947,0.55088,1.22792,-0.92351,-0.09028,1.68379,-0.61077,1.28104,-0.92225,-0.57811,0.7687)
fore1 <- c(0.902837,2.4492678,3.2075581,2.4383221,2.7751086,0.5931617,0.1085186,0.8785177,-1.165313,0.5937193,-0.003627,0.9943153,0.5194248,0.285099,0.5713786,0.2233359,0.327581,0.0846889,-0.083991,-0.073104)
fore2 <- c(0.8945434,2.3213521,2.5208157,1.908075,0.9507821,-0.610665,-1.11545,1.1116309,-2.777648,1.51728,0.4897679,1.047002,-1.344792,0.0019235,1.7465681,-1.063168,1.2719837,-1.289334,-0.464421,0.9785314)
DM.test(f1=fore1,f2=fore2,y=Actual,loss="SE",h=4,c=FALSE,H1="same")
```

> statistic = 1.0302, forecast horizon = 4, p-value = 0.3029 (very close)

It's close to the article anwser, but when I using h = 20, the output return "NA"

> statistic = NaN, forecast horizon = 20, p-value = NA

even h = 13

> statistic = NaN, forecast horizon = 13, p-value = NA

What does the "h" mean?

I have confused about example dm.test. The example uses 80% as the training model, 20% as the test model with one-step-forecast, sets "h" = 1; however, if I use it in prediction n.step-forecast , what kind of "h" should I select?

one-step-forecast

```
f1 <- ets(WWWusage[1:80])
f2 <- auto.arima(WWWusage[1:80])
f1.out <- ets(WWWusage[81:100],model=f1)
f2.out <- Arima(WWWusage[81:100],model=f2)
accuracy(f1.out)
accuracy(f2.out)
dm.test(residuals(f1.out),residuals(f2.out),h=1)
```

n-step-forecast

```
f1 <- ets(WWWusage[1:80])
f2 <- auto.arima(WWWusage[1:80])
f1.out <- forecast.ets(f1,h=20)
f2.out <- forecast(f2,h=20)
dm.test(WWWusage[81:100]-f1.out$mean , WWWusage[81:100]-f2.out$mean , h= 20)
```

> DM = 0, Forecast horizon = 20, Loss function power = 2, p-value = 1

what is rule to select h when the example "forecast(f2,h=20)"?

Comment: Thanks for a reproducible example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by

> assume I set a ARIMA model to forecast n-ahead = 20 (using dynamic regression not one step forecast)

In any case, the role of $h$ is as follows:

- at time $t$ you predict $y_{t+h}$,
- at time $t+1$ you predict $y_{(t+1)+h}$,
- ...,
- at time $t+s$ you predict $y_{(t+s)+h}$.

Note that the forecast horizon is constant and equal to $h$ in each case.* Then you

- wait until the (end of) time period $(t+s)+h$,
- obtain the realized values $y_{t+h},\dots,y_{(t+s)+h}$,
- compare the forecasts to the realized values and
- collect the forecast errors.

You do this for two or more methods. Then you can test whether the expected value of forecast loss from the first forecast equals the expected value of the forecast loss of the second (or maybe several more) forecasts using the Diebold-Mariano test. In such a situation, you set `h=h` in the function options.

You are having a technical difficulty with setting $h=20$ in your particular example because the sample is too short for comparing forecasts of such long horizons. The method tries to estimate the long-run variance of the mean loss differential based on $20$ lags, and a sample of only $20$ observations is too short for that. Meanwhile, it works OK for values of $h$ up to 12, since you can (although with questionable accuracy) estimate the long-run variance using $12$ lags from a sample of $20$ observations.

*This is in contrast to predicting $1,\dots,h$ steps ahead from a fixed origin at time $t$. The Diebold-Mariano test is not suited for such situations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still have some questions. I read the dm.test example from forecast package, in the example select dm.test( ,h=1) becasuse of using one-ahead-forecast to predict ? In this case, is it reasonable if I select dm.test( ,h = 2、3)? Then If predict is n.ahead-forecast which dm.test forecast horizon should use?(is dm.test(h=1) acceptable?)

Comment: @Ivan, I do not understand your question, could you try to state it even more clearly? I have covered the most common types of applications of the DM test in my answer. I do not think the DM test is suited for other types of applications, so if yours is such, then you probably cannot apply the test.

Comment: @Ivan, now I have noticed you have edited your question. I see what you are doing there. I covered this in *(This is in contrast to predicting $1,\dots,,h$ steps ahead from a fixed origin at time $t$.)* To reiterate, you cannot apply the Diebold-Mariano test in such a situation.

Comment: Hello Professor! But I'm thinking , is it because of  n-step-forecast with fixed t, the uncertainty of out of sample prediction will increase with the increase of time t, result d mean(loss-differential) and VaR (d) presenting non-stationary, so that  can't be used? In article, the excel example seems doesn't mention fixed n-step-forecast or one-step-forecast, and set h=n^(1/3)+1 even have 20 sample of forecast.

Comment: @Ivan, yes, your logic up to the question mark makes sense. I have not checked the article, but plenty of online materials contain mistakes or imprecisions, so consider this a possibility (not to say this actually is the case -- just a possibility). The statement *It is generally sufficient to use the value $g = n^{1/3} + 1$* (I use $g$ to distinguish from the forecast horizon $h$) suggests an approximation to the naive estimate of long-run variance with $h$ lags when $h>n^{1/3} + 1$, and it may or may not be a good one depending on the details of the problem.

Comment: Thank you, Professor, for your detailed explanation, I have benefited a lot. I think I probably understand that h-step-forecast will be a rolling forecast in dm.test, not a fixed from time t.

Comment: @Ivan, that sounds correct.